# Perl Regex: negate character class gives unexpected results

Tags: perl

Wondering if anyone else if having an issue with perl 5.14 on ubuntu 12.04 when it comes to negating a character class in Perl.

Given the following small snippet

```
while(<>) {

    print if /[^Dd]an/;
}
```

With the following small input

```
Dan
Frank
Steve
daniel
```

I would expect

```
Frank
Steve
```

to be printed to the terminal instead I get Frank only.

Just wondering if anyone else was having a similar issue and figured out what the problem was.  I'm going to search around for a bit and see if I can come up with anything I'll update if I find anything

Cheers

Comment: `print if ! /[Dd]an/;`

Answer (score 4):

The regular expression

```
/[^Dd]an/
```

Does indeed not match `Steve`. Basically, you're matching all lines with the sequence `an`, except those preceeding with a `D` or `d`. I don't see how you expect it to match Steve.

I think the behaviour is correct. Keep in mind that the negation is only applying to the characters within the `[]` section.